# Oscilloscope (Rigol DS1054) displaying two mirrored signal traces?

Tags: circuit-analysis, signal, oscilloscope

My scope is showing two of the same signals about 50mv apart no matter voltage I'm measuring. Is this an issue with my scope or is there a function I'm missing? Can someone please tell me what going on?

[image]

Comment: make a single shot and/or zoom, your signal is oscillating, the scope is always showing multiple over each other. you can also reduce the memory used, many ways to skin the cat.

Comment: *My scope is showing two of the same signals about 50mv apart no matter voltage* **No it's not** it is showing a signal which is at the higher voltage (top trace) half the time and at the lower voltage the other half of the time. It's not triggering correctly either so it plots the two curves this way. Hook the probe to the top test clip at the far right on the front of the scope and press "Auto" now play with the settings until you get a similar picture as you show here. You need to learn how to operate an oscilloscope so get busy and try all settings out.

Comment: "Period <200us" and time scale is... 10 ms/div.

Comment: PlasmaHH, I don't see why my signal is oscillating if I'm measure a battery.

Comment: You are probably picking up some fluorescent or LED power supply interference. What is the source of the light under the scope?